# How to add a lock in this situation?

Tags: java, multithreading

Code like this...

```
public void beforeUpdated(Log log){
    synchronized(this){
       query(log);
       merge(log);
       persist(log);
    }
}
```

This method is running under the multi-thread environment.The logs' CRUD must be an atomic operation.But only log of same id(log.getUuid()) need be synchronized.If I lock all the operation,it must have been a poor performance.I just hope that the logs of the same id lock under an atomic operation.How should I do like this?Please help me if you have any idea,thanks.

Comment: I would add everything to a single threaded background thread pool. If this is fast enough, you don't need any additional locking.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this situation a few times. What you need is a singleton LockFactory that is actually a dictionary of weak references for lock objects. the code should be something like:

```
class LockFactory {
    private LockFactory() {}
    private LockFactory instance = null;
    public static LockFactory getInstance() { 
        if (this.instance == null)
            this.instance = new LockFactory();
        return this.instance;
    }
    private int _last_check_size = 0;
    private int _cleanup_size = 1000;
    private Map<String, WeakReference> weakRefDictionary = new HashMap<String, WeakReference>();
    public object getLock(String id) {
        synchronized(this) {
             if (!this.weakRefDictionary.containsKey(id))
                 this.weakRefDictionary.put(id, new WeakReference(null));
             Object lock = this.weakRefDictionary.get(id).Target;
             if (lock == null) { 
                lock = new Object();
                this.weakRefDictionary.get(id).Target = lock;
             }
             if (this.weakRefDictionary.size() > this._last_check_size + this._cleanup_size)
                  this._do_cleanup();
             return lock;
        }
    }
    public void _do_cleanup() {
        synchronized(this) {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, WeakReference>> iter = this.weakRefDictionary.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String,WeakReference> entry = iter.next();
                if (entry.getValue().get() == null) {
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }
            this._last_check_size = this.weakRefDictionary.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Now to use in your case just do:

```
public void beforeUpdated(Log log){
    synchronized(LockFactory.getInstance().getLock(log.getUuid())){
       query(log);
       merge(log);
       persist(log);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't the lock be discarded almost immediately as there is no other strong reference to it when its not being locked.

Comment: There is a reference while it is being used since the object is kept in the stack until it is released

Comment: If you use a WeakHashMap, it cleans up dead keys for you.

Comment: @idanzalz: Thank you, guys.Last time , I just wanted to maintain a map with the strategy that it will cleanup at a definite time.The map value is a buffer, it will merge all the log and while the time is out ,it will do the saving operation and cleanup the map of this key. After seeing this,I think that this is a good practice.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:Thanks peter also,yeah in java we may use WeakHashMap with a strategy of cleanup .This made my eyes lit up :D

Comment: @idanzalz:One more question,<code>if (this.WeakRefDictionary.Count > this._last_check_size + this._cleanup_size)</code> means?Why you need a last_check_size?Why not 'count > cleanup_size'?Does the purpose of this code prevent stack from overflowing ?

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure you can use a WeakHashMap here since it keeps the __key__ weakly referenced, not the target.  Maybe there's a way to rewrite everything to use that correctly, but I don't see it... I haven't looked at it very hard however.

Comment: @toto2, Only the key is used externally. The value is a dummy lock object.

Comment: @Peter OK, I didn't understand that both the key and the value will then be weak references. Wicked.

Comment: @toto2, Only the key are weak referenced, the values are created by the method and will only be referenced when used. When the key is cleaned up, so is the value.

Comment: @Bobby the reason why we need last check size, is that in steady state we can have many locks and that's ok, since they are in use. assume the size is 1000, and we have 1000 locks in steady state, then any creation will cause a cleanup which is wasteful. If we cleaned and got left with a 1000 locks we want to check again when we get to 2000 and not before that. BTW, how come my answer was accepted and now it doesn't look that way?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I dpn't think you can use a WeakHashMap here since we need a Weak VALUE hash map (like python's WeakValueDictionary). This is because the key here is a string which we can't rely on being held by anyone. What we want is a dictionary that accepts a  key and an object and disposes both when the object is no longer referenced (not the key). [Here is a link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/WeakValueHashMap.htm) for an implementation I found for that in java

Comment: @PeterLawrey I found weak value map class like 'org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap' It's in commons-collections.jar.I'am also confused about this code '!kvp.Value.IsAlive'.I am not sure we have the same method to know whether the object is alive or referred in Java.

Comment: This is certainly not Java as it is supposed to look (or could compile, for each with var and in keywords?). If anyone of the boffins here can clear this up, it would be most helpful.

Comment: My bad, for some reason I thought it was c# (though the question was clear). Now it's in C#

Comment: Also fixed the problem with editing the dictionary while iterating

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a `HashMap` that maps the log ids that have been encountered so far to some `Object`, and synchronize on the `Object` that belongs to the id of the log being written to. Note that reads and writes to the `HashMap` must be synchronized on the `HashMap` itself.

Comment: You need a HashMap so you can perform get() to find the matching object. A set won't give you the matching object.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to do something like:

```
class Log
{
    private static final WeakHashMap<String, Object> LOCKS = 
        new WeakHashMap<String, Object>();

    private final String uuid;

    public Log(String uuid)
    {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public Object getLock()
    {
        synchronized (LOCKS)
        {
            Object lock = LOCKS.get(uuid);
            if (lock == null)
            {
                lock = new Object();
                LOCKS.put(uuid, lock);
            }
            return lock;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
public void beforeUpdated(Log log) 
{
    synchronized (log.getLock()) 
    {
       query(log);
       merge(log);
       persist(log);
    }
}
```

If the bottle-neck of acquiring the lock from the static weak map bothers you, you can try using something like [Guava MapMaker](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to construct a concurrent weak hash map.